# How to check buy/sell tax for pairs on ethereum-based blockchains

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, binance, binance-smart-chain

There's honeypot.is website to check, if token pair has any buy/sell tax.
But the problem is, that it requires BNB liquidity for token, so it works only for BNB/anythingelse pair.
I want to check, for example, BUSD/anythingelse pair, if it also has any taxes.
Didn't find suitable solutions. If there a way to check that? Maybe any source of smart contracts that can detect taxes, any information will be valuable.
I've found bscheck.eu website, but there's no information with what pairs does it work :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.